# How to print to HP Officejet without using HP Smart setup?

Tags: hp-officejet, hp

My lovely older neighbors got gifted a newish HP OfficeJet printer. They do not want to sign up with HP in order to use the printer. They only have a wifi set up at their home usually with no internet connection. Is this possible? I seemed to get it added to Windows via the wifi network, but when I printed a document, the screen showed a message that the setup needed to be completed at 123.hp.com.

Comment: No; It’s not possible. They can connect to the device through USB and perhaps share the device but there use case isn’t compatible with a wireless printer on the network

Comment: It's helpful when getting support for a product to list the Model #

Comment: Not intending to contradict @Ramhound but it appears that this may be possible according to HP, using WIFI-Direct.  If you provide the model # I will look into this further.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to get the model # when I was over there.  It is HP OfficeJet Pro 8020e series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article
[do i need hp smart app to use printer etc?](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printing-Errors-or-Lights-Stuck-Print-Jobs/do-i-need-hp-smart-app-to-use-printer-etc/td-p/8208503)
contains a useful
[answer](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printing-Errors-or-Lights-Stuck-Print-Jobs/do-i-need-hp-smart-app-to-use-printer-etc/td-p/8208503):

**Method - Use the Easy Start Wrapper to Install the Full Feature / Full Driver Software**

Full driver includes print and scan functions supported by your printer and provides the printer features on which other applications / software might depend.

- Open the webpage
  [HP Customer Support - Software and Driver Downloads](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/closure/hp-easy-start/7376041?ssfFlag=true&sku=)
  and wait for the download to start
- Once the download prompt appears, double-click to download the file
  `HPEasyStart_14_6_6.exe`
- Run the file as Administrator
- When asked, Select to install the "Full Driver" / "Full Feature Software"
- If using USB:  Connect the cable when instructed to do so (near the end of the installation process).
- About 2/3 of the way through the setup, you will be given the
  opportunity to select the software - select the "Full Driver" set
  (as opposed to the basic driver or other application).
- You can skip / ignore suggestion(s) that you add the HP Account – you’ll need the account at some point, for now, you can skip this suggestion (as many times as it insists it’s a good idea) during the full driver software installation.
- If you see it, you can skip / ignore suggestion(s) regarding Instant Ink subscription.  Instant Ink subscription is NOT mandatory.
- If the installation completes and then wants to loop around again, X out of the repeat menu / message to install again.
- After the software is installed, Restart the computer and log in.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the printer to the existing network, **you may attempt to [print via Wi-Fi Direct](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-officejet-pro-8020-all-in-one-printer-series/24208622/document/ish_1841315-1637332-16)**.

**In case this does not work as well and you refuse to use HP Smart, it's on you to bring the right drivers and install them manually.** There are [8020e drivers for offline usage on HP's webpage](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-officejet-pro-8020e-all-in-one-printer-series/38023432/model/2100184663) (please double check it's the right make and model, at the top you see the selected printer & target OS).

On the webpage you want to:

- close the "*recommended*" solution HP Smart,
- open *Installation Software and Full/Basic Driver-Supports print and scan functionality only*,
- then snatch the *HP OfficeJet Pro 8020 All-in-One EasyStart Printer Setup Software – Offline Use Only*.

It's probably best you load these onto a USB stick and bring them to your neighbors. Maybe guide them through the installation as well. After the drivers are installed, you should have no problems adding the driver in the native Windows printer selection. Both printing via the local network as well as WiFi-Direct should work flawlessly now.

Answer (score 0):

Go to
https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-officejet-pro-8720-all-in-one-printer-series/7902032/swItemId/bi-158263-6
and go to Source / Video help. Select category "Software and Drivers," scroll down to Related Videos, and find and watch the video for your setup.

This is from [a HP forum](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Setup-Software-Drivers/Install-printer-without-HP-Smart/td-p/8376485). Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).